# Javascript of accordion menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to construct an accordion menu as mentioned in:

[jsfiddle-link](http://jsfiddle.net/aesposito/ku3fwu92/)

HTML

```
<div class="content_slider">
  <div class="content_title" data-default-text="<b>Diagonal Slider</b><br/>by @innvenio">
    <div class="text">
      <b>Diagonal Slider</b>
      <br/>by @innvenio
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="gallery_content">
    <div class="gallery_item">
      <img src="http://static.innvenio.com/diagonalslider/images/1.jpg" data-title="Image 1" />
    </div>
    <div class="gallery_item">
      <img src="http://static.innvenio.com/diagonalslider/images/2.jpg" data-title="Image 2" />
    </div>
    <div class="gallery_item">
      <img src="http://static.innvenio.com/diagonalslider/images/3.jpg" data-title="Image 3" />
    </div>
    <div class="gallery_item">
      <img src="http://static.innvenio.com/diagonalslider/images/2.jpg" data-title="Image 4" />
    </div>
    <div class="gallery_item">
      <img src="http://static.innvenio.com/diagonalslider/images/1.jpg" data-title="Image 5" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0px;
}

.content_title {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 50px 40px 50px 80px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  z-index: 100;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-left: -60px;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) skew(-20deg, 0deg);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) skew(-20deg, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) skew(-20deg, 0deg);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) skew(-20deg, 0deg);
}

.content_title .text {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) skew(20deg, 0deg);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) skew(20deg, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) skew(20deg, 0deg);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) skew(20deg, 0deg);
}

.content_slider {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.gallery_content {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: -170px;
}

.gallery_item {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-left: -2px;
  -webkit-transition: width 500ms;
  -moz-transition: width 500ms;
  -o-transition: width 500ms;
  transition: width 500ms;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) skew(-20deg, 0deg);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) skew(-20deg, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) skew(-20deg, 0deg);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) skew(-20deg, 0deg);
}

.gallery_item img {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) skew(20deg, 0deg);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) skew(20deg, 0deg);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) skew(20deg, 0deg);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) skew(20deg, 0deg);
}
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function loadSlider(slider,default_text){
    var w;
    var width = 0;
    var image_width = slider.find('.gallery_item img').width();
    var image_height = slider.find('.gallery_item img').height();
    var out = true;
    var valor = 0;        
    var length_gallery_item = slider.find('.gallery_item').length;

    valor = length_gallery_item * 25;
    if($(window).width()<1060){
        valor = length_gallery_item * 40;
    }
    w = $(window).width() + ($(window).width() / length_gallery_item) + valor;
    width = w / 3;
    slider.width(w);
    slider.height($(window).height());
    slider.find('.gallery_item').width((w / length_gallery_item));
    slider.find('.gallery_item img').css('margin-left', ((image_width / 2) * -1) + (w / length_gallery_item));
    if($(window).height()<image_height){            
        slider.find('.gallery_item img').css('top', ((image_height-$(window).height())/2)*-1);
    }
    var i = 1;
    slider.find('.gallery_item').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('data-position', i);
        i++;
    });

    height_img = slider.find('.gallery_item img').height();

    if(height_img<slider.height()){
        slider.height(height_img);
    }

    $('.content_slider').find('.content_title').css('margin-top',slider.height() - 200); 

    slider.find('.gallery_item').unbind("hover");
    slider.find('.gallery_item').hover(function(){
        if (out){
            zoomIn($(this), function(){
                out = false;    
            }); 
        }

    }, function(){
        zoomOut(function(){
            out = true; 
        });
    });

    function zoomOut(callback){
        slider.find('.gallery_item').each(function(){
            var x = w / length_gallery_item;
            $(this).css('width', x);
        });
        $('.content_slider').find('.content_title .text').html(default_text);
        callback();
    }

    function zoomIn(item, callback){
        slider.find('.gallery_item').each(function(){
            var x = (w / length_gallery_item) - (width / length_gallery_item-1);
            if ($(this).attr('data-position') != item.attr('data-position')){
                $(this).css('width', x);
            }
            else
            {
                item.css('width', ((w / length_gallery_item) + width) - ((width / length_gallery_item) * 1.5));
                var title = item.find('img').attr('data-title');
                $('.content_slider').find('.content_title .text').html(title);
            }
        });
        callback();
    }
}

(function($) {
    $.fn.createDiagonalSlider = function() {
        var slider = $(this);
        var doit;
        var default_text = $('.content_slider').find('.content_title').attr('data-default-text');

        setTimeout(function(){
            loadSlider(slider, default_text);
        }, 10);

        function resizedw(){
            loadSlider(slider, default_text);
        }
        window.onresize = function() {
            clearTimeout(doit);
            doit = setTimeout(function() {
                resizedw();
            }, 100);
        };

    }
}(jQuery));

</script>
```

But seems there is an issue there which results broken slider (accordion) there. Instead of showing the image one upon other, it is showing one after another. [Here is the site I am working on:](http://test.techkalph.com/)

You can see the error below the menu of the home page.

Please someone take a look into it and kindly correct me.

Thank you.

Comment: Show us your code...

Comment: I have edited my previous reply. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

That's not an error that's the first image tag. The reason it's visible instead of the image itself might be because the tag is missing the leading "<".

Now you have

```
img src="http://test.techkalph.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/golf-course-srinagar.jpg" data-title="Image 1"/>
```

But you should probably have

```
<img src="http://test.techkalph.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/golf-course-srinagar.jpg" data-title="Image 1"/>
```

I can't point out more than that without the code. Could you add the code to your post?

EDIT:

Do you ever call the createDiagonalSlider() function?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.gallery_content').createDiagonalSlider();
});
```

Comment: I have edited my previous reply. Please have a look.

Comment: You seem to never actually call the createDiagonalSlider() function.

Comment: No, I have added only that much of code I mentioned above. Where do I actually put the above code that you have mentioned above?

Comment: It doesn't really matter. Anywhere browser can read it is okay.

I see you have already put it in your page, abowe loadSlider function. That's a good place.

Now you only need to add jQuery to your site to make it all work.

Comment: I have added all the codes that given in this link:

http://jsfiddle.net/aesposito/ku3fwu92/

But not sure what more jQuery is needed. So if it is possible can you please suggest what code I have missed from the above link.

Comment: The problem is you're getting error "TypeError: $ is not a function" on "$(document).ready"

Most likely some other JavaScript library conflicts with jQuery on this. You can try to fix it by changing all dollar signs ($) into "jQuery" (without the quotes of course).

I'll modify my answer's code accordingly.